# How to prove $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\tan^{a} (x) \;dx}{x^2+b^2}=\frac{\pi}{2b}\frac{\tanh^{a} (b)}{\cos\frac{a\pi}{2}}$

Tags: integration

I'm having trouble to prove the following:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\tan^{a}\left(x\right)}
{x^{2} + b^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}x =
\frac{\pi}{2b}\,\frac{\tanh^{a}\left(b\right)}{\cos\left(\pi a/2\right)}\quad
\mbox{where}\ \left\vert a\right\vert < 1\
\mbox{and}\ b > 0
$$
The main difficulty is that the sign of the $\tan\left(x\right)$  alternates between positive and negative and so we need $\left(-1\right)$ to raise to power of noninteger number $a$.

I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: I think the main problem is that $\tan x$ produces infinitely many improperties: $\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$ for $k\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: BTW, maybe trying to use Residue Theorem with $f(z)=\frac{\tan z}{z^2+b^2}$ would be an idea

Comment: @TitoEliatron what contour do you recommend

Comment: $[-R,R]$ plus the upper semicircle centered at the origin and radius $R$. This is classical. What is differentt here is the function, but taking into account that $\Im(\tan(z))=\frac{\sinh(2y)}{\cos(2x)+\cosh(2y)}$, it may works. (or maybe $\tan(z/2)/(z^2+b^2)$).
Just guessing...

Comment: No, that contoyur I think will not work since the singularities of $\tan$ would be in the contour. BUT, since those singularities lies in teh positive real line, maybe taking $[-R,0]+[0,Ri]+C$, where $C$ is the quarter of circle.

Comment: Call me nuts, but if there are values for $x$ for which the function does not exist AND these are asymptotic values (non removable discs), how can you just come up with an integral AND expect an answer?

Comment: I don't think this formula is provable as it is is.  Tan goes negative and the left hand side will have complex contributions for real a.  The right hand side stays real.

Comment: Besides the jumps at $\left.\vphantom{\Large A} k\pi + \pi/2\,\right\vert_{\,k\ \in\ \mathbb{N},\,\,\,}$ you have branch-cuts of $\tan^{a}\left(x\right)$ -thanks to the exponent $a$-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integrand has poles at $x=\pm ib$ and singularities on the real axis at $x=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$ with cuts where the tangent becomes negative. Nevertheless, the integral can be viewed as a complex contour in the upper half-plane with the segment $(-\infty,\infty)$ shifted slightly by $+i0$ to avoid the singularities and make the integrand holomorphic in the upper half-plane except at $x=ib$. Let
$$C_R=(-R,R) \cup \gamma_R$$
be the closed contour where $\gamma_R$ is the large semi-circle counter-clockwise in the upper half-plane of radius $R$ s.t. $R\neq (2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$. Since the tangent is bounded on $\gamma_R$, the integral over the arc $\gamma_R$ vanishes in the limit $R \rightarrow \infty$. Using the residue theorem for the limiting closed contour $C_\infty$, we arrive at
$$\frac{\pi}{b} \, \tan^a(ib) = \int_{C_\infty} \frac{\tan^a(x)}{x^2+b^2} \, {\rm d}x = \int_{-\infty+i0}^{\infty+i0} \frac{\tan^a(x)}{x^2+b^2} \, {\rm d}x = (e^{i\pi a}+1) \int_0^{\infty} \frac{|\tan(x)|^a}{x^2+b^2} \, {\rm d}x  \,. \tag{1}$$
Rearranging gives the desired result.

Technically the last step is a bit more intricate than it appears at first sight. When substituting $x\rightarrow -x$ for the segment $(-\infty+i0,i0)$, it becomes $(-i0,\infty-i0)$ which matters because it changes the phase of the tangent. When $\tan(x)$ becomes negative, it has phase $+\pi$ for $\Im(x)>0$ and $-\pi$ for $\Im(x)<0$. This can be seen for e.g. $x\in(-\pi/2+i0,i0)$ and the fact that for $x$ close to $0$, $\tan(x) \approx x$ and hence they share the same phase properties i.e. $$\arg(\tan(x))=\arg(x)=\arg(-1+i0)=\arg(e^{i\pi})=\pi$$ and by the periodicity this translates to $\mathbb{R}$.

Therefore the correct sequence of steps leading to the RHS of (1) is as follows:
$$\int_{i0}^{\infty+i0} \frac{\tan^a(x)}{x^2+b^2} \, {\rm d}x + \int_{-i0}^{\infty-i0} \frac{(-\tan(x))^a}{x^2+b^2} \, {\rm d}x \\
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \int_{n\pi + i0}^{n\pi +\pi/2+i0} \frac{\tan^a(x)}{x^2+b^2} \, {\rm d}x + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{n\pi + \pi/2 + i0}^{n\pi + \pi+i0} \frac{\tan^a(x)}{x^2+b^2} \, {\rm d}x \\
+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \int_{n\pi - i0}^{n\pi +\pi/2 - i0} \frac{(-\tan(x))^a}{x^2+b^2} \, {\rm d}x + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{n\pi + \pi/2 - i0}^{n\pi +\pi - i0} \frac{(-\tan(x))^a}{x^2+b^2} \, {\rm d}x \, .$$
The argument inside $(\dots)^a$ of the first and last term is positive (on this part of the decomposed domain), i.e. the integrand has phase $0$ and both terms can be combined to $\int_0^\infty \frac{|\tan(x)|^a}{x^2+b^2} \, {\rm d}x$. The second term has $\Im(x)>0$ and thus phase $+\pi$. Likewise in the third term $\Im(x)<0$ and hence $-\tan(x)$ has phase $+\pi$ also. Pulling out the phase and using absolute values instead, these two terms combine to $e^{i\pi a} \int_0^\infty \frac{|\tan(x)|^a}{x^2+b^2} \, {\rm d}x$
giving the RHS of (1).

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution is inspiring. I still have to digest it

Comment: Hey, I modified my post; so actually you need $|\tan(x)|$.

Answer (score 1):

if we try letting $x=iy\Rightarrow dx=idy$ and $(0,\infty)\rightarrow(0,\infty)$. We then know that:
$$\tan(iy)=i\tanh(y)$$
$$\frac{1}{(iy)^2+b^2}=\frac{1}{b^2-y^2}$$
so our integral becomes:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{i^{a+1}\tanh^a(y)}{b^2-y^2}dy$$
now you can do factor: $b^2-y^2=(b+y)(b-y)$ and also notice that:
$$i^{a+1}=(e^{i\pi/2})^{a+1}=\cos\left(\frac{(a+1)\pi}{2}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{(a+1)\pi}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Your approach fails at a=0. The original integral gives real value while your transformed integral gives a pure  imaginary value.

Comment: @MartinGales The integral is trivial at $a=0$ anyways

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer. Just an extended comment.

After using partial fractions expansion for cotangent function this integral can be reduced to
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\tan^ax}{\cosh 2b-\cos2x}dx=\frac{\pi\tanh^{a}\left(b\right)}{2\cos\left(\pi a/2\right)\sinh 2b}.
$$
Then, after the substitution $\tan x=t$, it becomes
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{t^a}{t^2+c^2}dt=\frac{\pi c^{a-1}}{2\cos\left(\pi a/2\right)},
$$
where we have denoted $c=\tanh b$.