# Help with $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos^k (x)}{a^2 + x^2} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, residue-calculus, trigonometric-integrals

I'm having trouble evaluating the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos^k(x)}{a^2+x^2} \, dx \,\text{ where } k \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } a >0$$
I've tried to follow [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3940242/how-to-prove-int-0-infty-frac-tana-x-dxx2b2-frac-pi2b?noredirect=1) which approaches tan instead.
$$I = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos^k(x)}{a^2 + x^2} \, dx$$

$$I = -i \int_{0}^{i \infty} \frac{\cosh^k(x)}{(a-x)(a+x)} \, dx$$
From here, I'm not sure how to progress.
I am aware of [the following expansions](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cos/16/07/05/) of $\cos^n$:
$$\cos^{2n} (z) = 2^{-2n} \binom{2n}{n} + 2^{1-2n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n}{k} \cos(2(n-k)z)$$
$$\cos^{2n} (z) = 1 + 2^{1-2n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n}{k}( \cos(2(n-k)z)-1)$$
$$\cos^{2n+1} (z) = 2^{-2n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{k} \cos((2n-2k+1)z)$$
$$\cos^{n} (z) = 2^{-n} \binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}(1- \, n \text{ mod } 2) + 2^{1-n} \sum_{k=0}^{ \lfloor{\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor}} \binom{n}{k} \cos((n-2k)z)$$
Based on @Claude Leibovici response, it is possible to evaluate the following two equations:
\begin{equation} 
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos^{2n} (x)}{a^2+x^2} \, dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(1-2 \,
   _2F_1\left(1,-n;n+1;-e^{2 a}\right)\right)}{2 a \Gamma (n+1)}+\frac{\pi  4^{-n}
   e^{-2 a n} \left(e^{2 a}+1\right)^{2 n}}{a}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos^{2n+1} (x)}{a^2+x^2} \, dx = \frac \pi a e^{-a (2 n+1)} (1-\tanh (a))^{-(2 n+1)}-
\frac{\sqrt{\pi } e^a \Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{a \Gamma (n+2)}{}_2F_1\left(1,-n;n+2;-e^{2 a}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Can I use a series expansion?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Ideally, I'd prefer a closed form, but feel free to give a series representation.

Comment: $$\cos(x)^{2n+1}
=\frac{1}{2^{2n}} \sum_{k=0}^{n} 
\frac{(2n+1)!}{k!(2n+1-k)!} \cos((2n+1-2k)x)$$

Comment: @KStarGamer Without Gaussian hypergeometric function, we have $I_{2m+1} = \frac{2}{2^{2m + 1}}\sum_{i=0}^m \binom{2m + 1}{i} \frac{\pi}{2a}\mathrm{e}^{- (2m + 1 - 2i) a}$ and $I_{2m} = \frac{1}{2^{2m}}\binom{2m}{m}\cdot \frac{\pi}{2a} + \frac{2}{2^{2m}}\sum_{i=0}^{m - 1}\binom{2m}{i} \frac{\pi}{2a}\mathrm{e}^{- 2(m - i) a}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least, for odd values of the exponent, the expansion given by @aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccc in comments is very useful since
$$\int_0^\infty \frac {\cos \big[ (2 n+1-2k)x\big] }{x^2+a^2}\,dx=\frac \pi{2a}\,\exp\big[-(2n+1-2k)a\big]$$ Summing from $k=0$ to $k=n$ then gives for
$$I_n=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos^{2n+1} (x)}{x^2+a^2 } \, dx$$
$$I_n=\frac \pi a e^{-a (2 n+1)} (1-\tanh (a))^{-(2 n+1)}-
\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \,e^a\, \Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right) \,
   }{a \,\Gamma (n+2)}\,_2F_1\left(1,-n;n+2;-e^{2 a}\right)$$ where appears the gaussian hypergeometric function.

Now,
$$\,_2F_1\left(1,-n;n+2;-e^{2 a}\right)=\frac{P_n(t)}{\binom{2 n+1}{n+1}} \qquad \text{where} \qquad t=e^{2a} $$ The first terms are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n(t) \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & t+3 \\
 2 & t^2+5 t+10 \\
 3 & t^3+7 t^2+21 t+35 \\
 4 & t^4+9 t^3+36 t^2+84 t+126 \\
 5 & t^5+11 t^4+55 t^3+165 t^2+330 t+462 \\
 6 & t^6+13 t^5+78 t^4+286 t^3+715 t^2+1287 t+1716 \\
 7 & t^7+15 t^6+105 t^5+455 t^4+1365 t^3+3003 t^2+5005 t+6435 \\
 8 & t^8+17 t^7+136 t^6+680 t^5+2380 t^4+6188 t^3+12376 t^2+19448 t+24310
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: This is great! I have added additional representations for cosine to some power- I don't know if they are at all useful for generalising it further than odd powers.